# How to sort the tuple string part in a list based on its float value in python?

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples, with a Str, float

```
list = 
[('Trading_State_NZ <= 0.00', 0.0234),
 ('Product_Type_A <= 0.00', 0.045643),
 ('Permanent_Resident_Y <= 1.00', 0.0214),
 ('Applicant_Type_B <= 1.00', 0.0236),
 ('Valuation_Acceptable_Y <= 1.00', 0.0866),
 ('Product_Type_6 <= 0.00', 0.0172),
 ('Trading_State_NT <= 0.00', 0.0553),
 ('Trading_State_TAS <= 0.00', 0.0251),
 ('Property_Acceptable_Y <= 1.00', 0.01588),
 ('Applicant_Type1_at1_miss <= 1.00', 0.0158758),
 ('Product_Type_I <= 0.00', 0.01571),
 ('Employer_Name <= 1.00', 0.0552),
 ('Business_Name <= 0.00', 0.02557),
 ('Product_Type_E <= 0.00', 0.02457),
 ('Product_Type_CTP <= 0.00', 0.02457),
 ('Trading_Postcode <= 1.00', 0.024572),
 ('Trading_State_ts_miss <= 1.00', 0.0785),
 ('Variation_2014 <= 0.00', 0.0694),
 ('Product_Type_C <= 0.00', 0.017145),
 ('Phone_Number <= 0.00', 0.0789678)]
```

The string part has two sections before and after <= symbol, "Name <= value", I am looking to separate 0.00 and 1.00 values then sort in descending order based on the float value

```
list.sort()
```

list.sort() sorting based on string, I need the split the str based on value and sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
type0 = []
type1 = []
for tup in mytups:
    if '<= 0' in tup[0]:
        type0.append(tup)
    else:
        type1.append(tup)

type0.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
type1.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

final_list = type0 + type1
```

Or using a multi level sort (shamelessly built upon @Selcuk answer):

```
mytups.sort(key=lambda x: (float(x[0].split("<=")[1]), -x[1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: -float(x[0].split("<=")[1]))
```

The `lambda` function simply splits the `0`th element of a tuple using `"<="` as a separator then converts the second part (`[1]`) of the split to a `float`. The `.sort()` method then uses this `lambda` function as the key.

Comment: @DSC From the question text: `[...] sorting based on string, I need the split the str based on value and sort`. They are talking about the float value after `<=`.